# Solve not finding a solution

Tags: equation-solving

Solve is timing out while trying to compute:

```
 Solve[(b*((Α^a*Β^b*Γ^c)/((β+Β)^b*(γ+Γ)^c))^(1/a))/(a*β+a*Β)==Ν/Μ,β]
```

For particular choices of a,b,c it will find a solution, but not for the general case.

In case it's helpful, that `a+b+c==1` is a valid constraint in this system.

Comment: It's not the problem here, but best to avoid `N` as a variable name because of its built-in meaning

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it, but you will probably need to verify the correctness of transformations as well as the solution by hand.

```
eqn=(b*((Α^a*Β^b*Γ^c)/((β+Β)^b*(γ+Γ)^c))^(1/a))/(a*β+a*Β)==Ν/Μ
eqn2=PowerExpand[Simplify[eqn /. β -> t - Β]]
Solve[eqn2, t] /. t -> β + Β
```